# How can I exclude two pages from optimization using Autoptimize snippet given below

Tags: code-snippets

I hope someone can help me here. How can I use this Autoptimize snippet to exclude two pages from optimization. The code below excludes the page "https//www.nameofsite/submit-an-article"

```
add_filter(‘autoptimize_filter_noptimize’,’submit_noptimize’,10,0);
function submit_noptimize() {
if (strpos($_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’],’submit-an-article’)!==false) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

I want to exclude also another page-->"https//:www.nameofsite.com/upload/file" I modified and tried to use the code below but it gave me an error.

```
    add_filter(‘autoptimize_filter_noptimize’,’submit_noptimize’,10,0);
    function submit_noptimize() {
    if (strpos($_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’],’submit-an-article’, 'upload- 
    file')!==false) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Perhaps, I did something wrong with code? Hope someone can help me here. I am just a newbie. Not really familiar in php. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//  Disable autoptimize on all pages with the words "term1" or "term2" in the URL
add_filter('autoptimize_filter_noptimize','my_ao_noptimize',10,0);

function my_ao_noptimize() {
   if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'term1')!==false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'term2')!==false) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```